# What is InjectedFormProps in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I am working on React-TypeScript project that is using Redux Form.

One of the component is using `InjectedFormProps` in Type Definition.

```
const Container: React.SFC<Props & InjectedFormProps<{}, Props>> = (props: Props & InjectedFormProps<{}, Props>) => {


return <> </>;

}
```

Can someone explain in detail what `InjectedFormProps` does under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redux-form/v7/lib/reduxForm.d.ts

```
export interface InjectedFormProps<FormData = {}, P = {}, ErrorType = string> {
    anyTouched: boolean;
    array: InjectedArrayProps;
    asyncValidate(): void;
    asyncValidating: string | boolean;
    autofill(field: string, value: any): void;
    blur(field: string, value: any): void;
    change(field: string, value: any): void;
    clearAsyncError(field: string): void;
    destroy(): void;
    dirty: boolean;
    error: ErrorType;
    form: string;
    handleSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormData, P, ErrorType>;
    initialize(data: Partial<FormData>): void;
    initialized: boolean;
    initialValues: Partial<FormData>;
    invalid: boolean;
    pristine: boolean;
    reset(): void;
    submitFailed: boolean;
    submitSucceeded: boolean;
    submitting: boolean;
    touch(...field: string[]): void;
    untouch(...field: string[]): void;
    valid: boolean;
    warning: any;
    registeredFields: { [name: string]: RegisteredField };
}
```

Comment: Pasting the typing in here is in no way and acceptable answer.

Comment: what should I do instead? explaining every type? can you elaborate? @JoelBourbonnais